# Correct usage of php PDO with mysql stored routines to fetch table data

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo

I would like to call mysql stored procedure with two in parameters say from and to and print the data in table. I have used the following code:

```
try
{       
    $age_from = $_POST['from'];
    $age_to = $_POST['to'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("CALL proc_report_filtered(:age_from,:age_to)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':age_from',$age_from);
    $stmt->bindParam(':age_to',$age_to);
    $records = $stmt->execute();
    $records->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{   
    die("Some problem getting data from database !!!" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Later I used while loop as before to print the table data.

```
while (  $report = $records->fetch()  )
```

Stored routine proc_report_filtered is a simple query to fetch data between the age range as follows:

```
select * from employee where age in between 30 and 40;
```

where 30 is $age_from and 40 is $age_to passed to stored routine.

Unfortunately the code doesnt work. Please correct me where I am going wrong. I am new to using php PDO.

Comment: Something I don't get. You have `query("call proc_report")` yet you're using `CALL proc_report_filtered(:n_c_from,:n_c_to)` in the other one. Are those 2 different procedures, or are you calling the wrong one?

Comment: See if you get anything out of http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and make sure those POST arrays contain values.

Comment: `$n_c_from` and `$n_c_to` is undefine in your code!!

Comment: @ Fred -- both are different procedures. First one works fine but the second one doesnt work ( proc_report_filtered )

Comment: and that's where error reporting would have been your friend here. I don't post that anymore ever since I've been bombed about it (last week or so).  But hey... why not, just for old times sake =>> http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php <<= ;-)

Comment: oh, nice Stealth edit there. without marking it as an edit saying you made an error.  Now I'm forced to reopen; lovely. Thanks for that

Comment: sorry for sharing the wrong code. I have corrected the try para in the second procedure. Please correct me. Excuse me for this mistake.

Comment: define "doesnt work as expected."

Comment: I mean it doesnt fetch data on the screen, it just shows a blank screen.

Comment: Sorry for mistakes in previous versions. I have re edited the question. Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is nothing essentially special in calling stored procedures with PDO. [The only issue](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call) may affect only *following* queries, but not the current one.

So, your problem is not related to stored procedures, but to the basic PDO syntax only: you are using wrong code to get the records. Here goes the proper one

```
$stmt->execute();
$records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In case it is not the issue but a copy/paste problem, and to help further visitors, here is a short check-list for the PDO debugging:

- **Step 1.** Run your query in a DB console to make sure it works by itself.
- **Step 2.** Make sure that you can see ALL PHP errors.

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1); // for the dev server only
  ```
- **Step 3.** Make sure that your PDO throws exceptions, by adding this code

  ```
  $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  ```
- **Step 4.** Run your query without prepared statements, using `PDO::query()`, with values written by hand:

  ```
  $stmt = $db->query("CALL proc_report_filtered(30,40)");
  ```
- **Step 5.** run with a prepared statement but in a simplified form, to eliminate all possible spelling issues:

  ```
  $stmt = $db->prepare("CALL proc_report_filtered(?,?)");
  $stmt->execute(array($_POST['from'],$_POST['to']));
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It helped me half way. How should I use (  $report = $records->fetch() ) in while loop again ?? As we already used $stmt->fetchAll already. Thanks once again.

Comment: Thank you for your time and detailed explanation. A small correction in step 5. The last statement should be "$records->execute(array($_POST['n_c_from'],$_POST['n_c_to'])); "